# IIS all files in the Scripts folder will not load (404, blank, text/plain)

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, qlikview

I am deploying an MVC site to production on IIS 7 which has been successfully deployed in a test environment. All components of the site load fine except for those contained in the Scripts folder. The pages returned are completely **blank**, with status code **404** and type **text/plain**. None of the requests to the Scripts folder show up in the IIS logs either. I've checked mime types, mappings, ISAPI, and everything looks fine. I've mimicked the test server settings as closely as I can.

Answer (score 0):

I found out this issue was caused by QlikView which was also installed on our server. It was intercepting the calls. This answers why the requests were not found in the logs.

My resolution is to use a different server to host my site.